span images over multiple divs, with space between
I'm trying to have one background image, spanning over multiple divs.
Below is an example of what the result should look like:

As you can see, it's one complete image, overlapping the 4 divs. In e.g. figma, I can just use masks to get the result, but in CSS is a bit more complex. Below is What I have tried:


body {
  background-color: #000;
  color: #fff;
}

.cards {
  width: 1024px;
  height: 500px;
  background-image: url('https://images.pexels.com/photos/12984738/pexels-photo-12984738.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&w=1260&h=750&dpr=1');
  background-size: cover;
}

.card {
  background-color: #2563eb;
  border-radius: 20px;
  background-color: #38bdf81a;
  background-image: linear-gradient(135deg, #0ea5e980 10%, #0000 0, #0000 50%, #0ea5e980 0, #0ea5e980 60%, #0000 0, #0000);
  background-size: 7.07px 7.07px;
}
<div class="grid grid-cols-3 gap-10 cards">
  <div class="col-span-2 card">this is some text</div>
  <div class="card">this is some text</div>
  <div class="card">this is some text</div>
  <div class="col-span-2 card">this is some text</div>
</div>



But there is a problem because the image is not in the boxes, it's in the cards section. How do I overlap the images so the result would be like the attached? Please note that it's important there is gap between the boxes.
https://codepen.io/pen?template=vYwqrWe

I've actually solved the issue.
The trick was to add pseudo elements, to ensure radius fits the container and not create remaining space:
[https://codepen.io/pen?template=GRabXKg][1]
.cards {
  max-width: 1000px;
  height: 300px;
  position:relative;
  background-color: #fff;
  
  img {
    position: absolute;
    object-fit: cover;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 1;
  }
  
  .card {
    border: 10px solid #fff;
    border-radius: 20px;
    z-index: 2;
    position: relative;
    
    &:before {
      content: '';
      position: absolute;
      width: calc(100% + 20px);
      height: calc(100% + 20px);
      border: 10px solid #fff;
      top: -10px;
      left: -10px;
      z-index: 3;
    }
  }
}


Yes, but it will break when the border-radius is larger.

yes, then you will have to recalculate
